# Display html table over Div Elements so that the table contents is not overlapping?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Html Page

```
<div *ngIf="visibleTournament">
  <div class = "row">
    <div *ngFor="let entry of competitionTeams | keys">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div (click) = "entry.hideme = !entry.hideme" (mouseleave)= "entry.hideme = false">
            <div class = "groupBox"><div class="placed"><h3><span class = "label label-warning">Group - {{entry.key}}</span></h3></div></div>
          </div>
            <div class="well box" [hidden] = "!entry.hideme">
              <table class="table">
                  <thead class="thead-inverse">
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Team</th>
                    <th>Played Games</th>
                    <th>Points</th>
                    <th>Goals</th>
                    <th>GA</th>
                    <th>GD</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                </table>
```

I want to Display a table when i click on a corresponding div on top of the Existing div's instead of the div's moving from their position. Also increase the Table width so that it is easily viewed.

My Css

```
.avatar{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.inline{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

.check{
  min-width: 500px;
}

.selector{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.placed{
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccffda;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width : 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: darkgray 1px solid;
}


.groupBox{
  text-align: center;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: darkgray 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.fix{
  position: absolute;
}
```

[image: Screen Look on load]
[image: How the Divs Move and also the table contents are Squeezed]

How to make the table appear on top if the existing elemnts and also increase the width of the table over the col width.

I am not that Expert on CSS please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to remove an element from the flow. This way, it won't push subsequent group boxes down. This will also make the element render [in front of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index) the other elements, which you also want.

When an element has `position: absolute`, its coordinate are resolved relative to a parent that also has `position` set to absolute or `relative`. Thus you may want to set `position: relative` on an ancestor so that you can align the `top` and `left` relative to the group, while still allowing the group to make room for itself.

Comment: The problem is when using position absoulte, only last three elements shows up as i am using ngFor and all the div's are in a loop.I am not able to figure this out . I know it will come up with absolute but i am not able to figure it out